# Authentication for Flask-based API?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-authentication

I've built out an API via Flask views, which users access using some endpoints at `/api/v1/....`. I'd like to authenticate users who make requests. What are ways to enforce authentication with my API? Is there a way to avoid building out a user model, and instead use Google or Github-based authentication?

Comment: I think Flask-OAuth or Flask-OAtuthlib will helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I use flask-login which intercepts web requests with sessions and ones with a header. Requests from the web use Flask's session, requests from mobile apps send a header.

These methods return users for the given request. The API token is signed (tamperproofed) by itsdangerous, which powers Flask's cookies.

```
from itsdangerous import URLSafeSerializer, BadData
serializer = URLSafeSerializer(CONFIG['SECRET_KEY'])


def load_user_from_request(request):
    token = request.headers.get('API-TOKEN')
    if token:
        try:
            user_id = serializer.loads(token)["id"]
            user = User.query.filter(User.active == True, User.id == int(user_id)).first()
            if user:
                return user
        except BadData as e:
            pass
    return None


def load_user(id):
    user = User.query.filter(User.active == True, User.id == int(id)).first()
    if not user:
        return None
    return user

login_manager.user_loader(load_user)
login_manager.request_loader(load_user_from_request)
```

This endpoint takes in an authentication request, checks the username and password and issues a token. The itsdangerous serializer makes a tamperproof version of your object. The client submits the same as a header. As long as the app's secret key is safe, your servers can confirm that signed objects were issued by your servers.

```
@blueprint.route('/api_auth', methods=["post"])
def api_auth():
   ...check username and password
    return response({
        'API-TOKEN': serializer.dumps({'id': user.id})
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like you are using a local user model though -- I was wondering if anyone had implemented anything similar while using a 3rd-party authentication system.

Comment: There is no reason why the user "model" should be in some database. Flask-login could use an API for the action of logging in.